# XDT Transform attribute with namespace

Tags: xdt-transform, xdt

i'm working on nuget package for xamarin.android and i need to transform AndroidManifest.xml
what i need is to add android:sharedUserId attribute to root element called manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >
    <!-- some another nodes -->
</manifest>
```

so I can add attribute to root node with

```
<manifest xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"
    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(sharedUserId)"
    sharedUserId="com.random.userId">
</manifest>
```

but namespace 'android' is missed. how to add namespace to attribute?